# SMS messages blocked in Ionic 2 *ngFor

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using SMS messages in my ionic 2 App.  I have the newest version of Cordova CLI and latest version of Ionic 2.

When I use

```
<a href="sms:14038000000"><button outline><ion-icon name="ios-chatbubbles"></ion-icon></button></a>
```

It works fine as sms:14038000000,

when I use

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of corp">
    <div class="contact-name">
        {{ item.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="contact-content">
        <a href="sms:{{item.sms}}"><button outline><ion-icon name="ios-chatbubbles"></ion-icon></button></a>
    </div>
</ion-card>
```

The SMS comes up as unsafe:sms:14038000000

In ionic 1 app.js I used

```
.config(function($compileProvider){
   $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|http?|ftp|mailto|file|sms|tel):/);
})
```

To solve this issue.

Is there a similar solution for Ionic 2 app.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice job sebaferreras!  For newer ionic2/ng2 version. please use the code below:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

add the service to constructor:

```
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer)
```

the method: return type use any.  Some said use SafeUrl, but somehow the new service doesn't have that.

```
public sanitize(url: string):any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

Html view same as sebaferreras's answer:

```
<a [href]="sanitize('sms:' + item.sms)">
```

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeHuang for bringing this out :)

Answer (score 5):

**UPADTE**

**Just like @George Huang mentioned, `DomSanitizationService` was renamed to `DomSanitizer` in Angular RC 6.**

All you need to do to avoid Angular2 marking your `href` as unsafe, is to import `DomSanitizer` like this:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Create an instance in your constructor:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, ...) { 
    //...   
}
```

And then use the `bypassSecurityTrustUrl(...)` method like this:

```
sanitize(url:string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

Finally, in your view use that method:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of corp">
    <div class="contact-name">
        {{ item.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="contact-content">
        <a [href]="sanitize('sms:' + item.sms)"><button outline><ion-icon name="ios-chatbubbles"></ion-icon></button></a>
    </div>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

---

**Old answer:**

All you need to do to avoid Angular2 marking your `href` as unsafe, is to import `DomSanitizationService` like this:

```
import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Create an instance in your constructor:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService, ...) { 
    //...   
}
```

And then use the `bypassSecurityTrustUrl(...)` method like this:

```
sanitize(url:string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

Finally, in your view use that method:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of corp">
    <div class="contact-name">
        {{ item.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="contact-content">
        <a [href]="sanitize('sms:' + item.sms)"><button outline><ion-icon name="ios-chatbubbles"></ion-icon></button></a>
    </div>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I have been looking at examples of DomSanitizationService.  But your explanation was easy to understand.  I going to spend some more time in the docs to get my head around this better.

Comment: Glad I could help :)